# Silverlight MVVM GridView not updating -- because of Row Virtualization?

Tags: silverlight, gridview, mvvm

I have a GridView bound to a ViewModel.  The user can edit one field on the rows by selecting one and then using a textbox below.  Before saving, the gridview should update with the new field.  It does update before saving, however, the user must first scroll the row out and back in the gridview.  I think this is because of Row Virtualization.  How do I fix this so the GridView updates immediately from the user changing the textbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any more information, I'm guessing your model dosn't implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx).

The link above explains how this should be done. Make sure you raise a `PropertyChanged` event after the data has been changed.